# SQLite CREATE query in QT

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

```
dataBase = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
dataBase.setDatabaseName("login_password.sqlite");

QSqlQuery authQuery;

if(!dataBase.open())
{
    qDebug() << dataBase.lastError().text();
}

QString create("CREATE TABLE BASE(LOGIN VARCHAR(15) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, "
               "PASSWRD TEXT(50) NOT NULL, RIGHTS INT NOT NULL);");

bool state = authQuery.exec(create);
if(!state) qDebug() << "Не удалось создать таблицу!";
```

What's wrong with query and is it possible to make text PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: What's the error message you get from `QSqlQuery::lastError()`?

Comment: Unrelated, but that `PASSWRD TEXT(50)` sounds like you are going to store password in cleartext in your database, which is definitely a bad idea...

Comment: @MatteoItalia no, I'm going to encrypt them, but it's univercity lab, so I should do it manually.

Comment: @Padmelina: fine, but remember that you don't want to *encrypt* them, you want to store only a *salted hash*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#details):

> Warning: You must load the SQL driver and open the connection **before** a
>   QSqlQuery is created. Also, the connection must remain open while the
>   query exists; otherwise, the behavior of QSqlQuery is undefined.

In your question, you are creating the `QSqlQuery` before opening the database, you have to move the `authQuery` declaration statement after the `dataBase.open()` call, like this:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("login_password.sqlite");
if (!db.open())
    qDebug() << "error opening database: " << dataBase.lastError().text();

QSqlQuery authQuery;
QString create("CREATE TABLE BASE(LOGIN VARCHAR(15) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, "
               "PASSWRD TEXT(50) NOT NULL, RIGHTS INT NOT NULL);");
if(!authQuery.exec(create)){
    qDebug() << "error executing statement: " << authQuery.lastError().databaseText();
}
```

Comment: Thank you I've copied accidentally opening after cresting query